# Javascript If statement for simple dinner tip calculator

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have this script that prompts for dinnerCost and taxRate to generate taxPaid. I want to make an if statement that makes sure that only integers are entered not strings.

here is my code:

```
<button id="btn"> Play the Dinner Game </button>

<p id="para"></p>



document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", dinnerThing);



function dinnerThing () {
        var cost = prompt("how much did it cost?");

        if(cost == "") {
            document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "sorry please enter an integer";    
        }

        var taxRate = prompt("What was the tax rate?");

        if(taxRate == "") {
            document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "sorry please enter an integer";    
        }



        var taxPaid = cost * taxRate;


        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "You paid " + taxPaid + " dollars in tax for your dinner";
}
```

Why is if statement not working here?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" You didn't show any input or output. Maybe edit your question to show this?

Comment: Is my code not showing?

Comment: as it stands, I want the if statement to make sure the user entered a valid value (a number).

Comment: Yes, your code is showing. You claim it doesn't work. But you don't show any output. You don't show what you typed. You don't explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: When it prompts me for how much did the dinner cost and I enter a string value like "Blah" it outputs this

Comment: You paid NaN dollars in tax for your dinner, and your cost was NaN

Comment: Thanks for assigning my answer as the accepted.  If you did find that it helped you, an up-vote would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both `if(cost == "")` and `if(taxRate == "")` are ***checking if the
>   variable (`cost1 or`taxRate`) is equal to an empty string, not if it
>   is equal to an integer***.

To ensure that you receive a value from prompt that is an Number you can use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will return a Number (integer or float) equivalent from a string.  If the string cannot be converted into a number, it returns NaN.

The steps would then be:

- get parseInt() values for cost and taxRate, store them in variables
- check if either of the previous variables returns is NaN using [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).
- If `isNaN()` returns `true`, then display "sorry please enter an integer" message
- If `isNaN()` returns `false`, then calculate taxPaid and output taxPaid value

The resulting code would look something like this:

```
var numberCost = parseInt(cost),
  numberTaxRate = parseInt(taxRate);

if(isNaN(numberCost) || isNaN(numberTaxRate)) {
   document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "sorry please enter an integer";  
}else{
  var taxPaid = cost * taxRate;
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "You paid " + taxPaid + " dollars in tax for your dinner";
}
```